# A random variation on Polya's orchard problem

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, euclidean-lattices

Polya's *orchard problem* is as follows:

> "How thick must the
>   trunks of the trees in a regularly spaced circular orchard grow if they are
>   to block completely the view from the center?"

See, e.g.,

> Allen, Thomas Tracy. "Polya's orchard problem."
>   *American Mathematical Monthly* (1986): 98-104.
>   [JSTOR link](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2322700?uid=3739256&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21104638182813)

or [this earlier MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/62922/6094).
This problem has been well-studied. One crude way to phrase what is known
is that, if the trees/disks centered at each lattice point have
radius $r$, the furthest distance one can see from the origin
is $R \approx 1/r$.

Here is my question. Suppose instead of disks centered on each
lattice point, we have a randomly oriented segment (a $1$-dimensional disk)
centered on each lattice point, of length $2r$, i.e., of radius $r$.

> **Q**. Is it still the case that the furthest one can see from the
>   origin is expected to be $R=c/r$ for some constant $c$?

Here is an example, with $r=3/8$. The "Polya radius"
is about $2.47$, but in this one random instance,
visibility extends about $3$ times further,
$R \approx 8$:

---

[image: Polya10]

---

In $\mathbb{R}^3$, the same question can be asked with now $2$-dimensional
randomly oriented disks centered on each lattice point.
And of course the question generalizes to $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: One might even guess that the expected size is all that matters, which would give $c=\pi/2$.

Comment: @WillSawin: Could you expand on your remark? I don't follow how you arrive at $\pi/2$...

Comment: I'm imagining looking through a long field of objects. It seems to me that the distance I see is going to be governed by the average visible angle the objects take up. For a line of radius $r$, this is $2/\pi$ times the visible angle of a disc of radius $r$. (average value of $\sin \theta$ for $0<\theta<\pi$).

Answer (score 5):

Probably this problem was not considered so far, but there are some related articles.

1. ["The distribution of free path lengths in the periodic Lorentz gas and related lattice point problems"](http://arxiv.org/abs/0706.4395v1)  by Jens Marklof, Andreas Strömbergsson.
   In partiqular they give the number of spheres in a random direction.
2. ["Visibility and directions in quasicrystals"](http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.1564)  by Jens Marklof, Andreas Strömbergsson. (In each direction points which are closed to a straight line form a "quasicrystal".)

3.["Perfect Retroreflectors and Billiard Dynamics"](http://arxiv.org/abs/0911.1984)  by Pavel Bachurin, Konstantin Khanin, Jens Marklof, Alexander Plakhov

See also [Marklof's talk](http://www.icm2014.org/vod/ICM-VOD-List.asp) at ICM-2014 (lecture I09_04) for an introduction.

I think that this authors can solve your problem in arbitrary dimension.