# Boomerangs in Polya's orchard

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, plane-geometry, euclidean-lattices

Polya's orchard problem asks for what radius $r$ of trees
at each lattice point within a distance $R$
of the origin block all lines of sight to the exterior of the orchard.
The answer is known; $r$ should be about $1/R$.
See
[this earlier question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/62922/6094)
for details and references.

Suppose instead of straight rays, visibility may follow
a circular arc (of any radius) from the origin.
Let $B=B(r)$ be the furthest distance visible
in the plane along any circular arc
when all lattice points (excluding the origin)
center disks of radius $r$.
It is easy to see that $B > R$,
where $R=\frac{\sqrt{1-r^2}}{r}$ is the Polya
distance determined by $r$:

---

[image: Boomerangs]

         

<sup>$r=\frac{1}{4}$, $R \approx 3.9$.</sup>


         

<sup>Two circular arc rays (of different radii)
from the origin to beyond $R$ are shown.</sup>

---

$B$ is finite for any $r>0$:
For otherwise the radius $a$ of the arc
that shoots to $\infty$ must itself be infinite.
But then it is a straight-line ray, and couldn't
reach further than Polya's $R$.

> ***Q***. Can anyone see an estimate of, or a bound on
>   $B$ as a function of the disk radius $r$?

Perhaps the furthest reaching arcs straddle the
disks on the $x$- and $y$-axes?

Comment: (entirely tangential comment: how the heck do you come up with these titles? most of the time I see one of your questions I open it because I cannot conceive how it is a mathematical question, and then I read it and realize that no other title can be better than the one you chose)

Comment: One possible (but really, really poor) bound is this. First make all the discs twice as big. Not you know that any curve that deviates from a straight line in sufficiently small manner will hit a disc in radius $R$. This contradicts a curve reaching distance $2\tilde{R}$ via a curve of radius of curvature $>\tilde{R}$ since within distance $R$ of origin the curve is "well approximated by a line". But this estimate is likely to be way bigger than what actually is there.  (What? I _am_ an analyst. :-p.)

Comment: @WillieWong: "O'Rourke quits faculty to pen tabloid headlines."